# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties error Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with Firebase and am trying to make a posts class. I keep getting the error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" when I try to initialize the variables. I am not really sure how to fix this error and not entirely sure what the problem is. I was wondering if anyone could help. Thank you.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class Posts {
     private var _username: String!
     private var _userImg: String!
     private var _postImg: String!
     private var _likes: Int!
     private var _postKey: String!
     private var _postRef: DatabaseReference

    var username: String{
        return _username
    }
    var userImg: String{
        return _userImg
    }

    var postImg: String{
        get{
            return _postImg
        }set{
            _postImg = newValue
        }
    }
    var likes: Int{
        return _likes
    }
    var postKey: String!{
        return _postKey
    }

    init(imgUrl: String, likes: Int, username: String, userImg: String){

        _postImg = imgUrl
        _likes = likes
        _username = username
        _userImg = userImg
        _postKey = nil
    } ///WHERE I GET THE ERROR

    init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        _postKey = postKey

        if let username = postData["username"] as? String{
            _username = username
        }

        if let userImg = postData["userImg"] as? String{
            _userImg = userImg
        }
        if let postImage = postData["imageUrl"] as? String{
            _postImg = postImage
        }
        if let likes = postData["likes"] as? Int {
            _likes = likes
        }

        _postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is clear. You have not given a value to all of the properties of your class in your `init` methods.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: By giving all of your properties (you have 6) a value.

Comment: Why do you have private properties and then have public read-only properties that simply access the private properties? The proper solution is simply have one line for each: `private (set) var username: String!`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the comments. After staring at if for a while, I realized I did not have an exclamation mark right after " private var _postRef: DatabaseReference
" so, I just added the "!" at the end and it worked.

OLD:
    private var _postRef: DatabaseReference

NEW:
   private var _postRef: DatabaseReference!

Comment: That's a bad solution. Why are all of your properties declared as implicitly unwrapped instead of optional?

Comment: Absolutely, reference type of things must not be forced unwrapped. Start using guard let or if let for optionals.

Comment: You've got a number of issues with that code and while it may work now, it's going to cause issues in the future.  This is a problem *_postKey = nil* because _postKey is not an optional. And the above two comments are on point as well - you need to protect your code (and your user) by using guard and if let statements to properly unwrap and handle optionals and don't force them to be something when they could be nil.